# what is the name of event?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

i wanna make event when i click on element and move cursor to another element then release cursor.
i made it using **mouseup** and **mousedown** events.
but some time **mouseup** not work!!!
the cursor change to hand and cant release it on another element.

```
for(var i=0;i<20;i++) {
   for(var j=0;j<20;j++) {
      var circle = document.createElement("div");
      circle.setAttribute("class","circle");
      circle.setAttribute("id",20*(i-1)+j);
      circle.setAttribute("style","left:"+(35*(j+1)+20*j)+"px;top:"+(10*(i+1)+20*i)+"px;");
      circle.addEventListener("mouseup",function() { ...});
      circle.addEventListener("mousedown",function() { ...});
      body.appendChild(circle);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mousedown and then mousemove away from the element, the mouseup event never fires.

Try adding preventDefault() to your mousedown handler...

```
  circle.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });
```

You may also try binding the mouseleave event to trigger the mouseup